# Separate class for Retrofit API client for each web service each having different types of headers

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using latest retrofit 2.0 for web service call.
I have three different type of webservice each having different JSON Request format.
Out of three one is image downloading web service.
All three web service takes different types of Headers (though same Authorization header) in Json request.
(I am using Interceptor to add header to my retrofit OkHttp client).

Should I have to create separate Retrofit API client for all the three web service to make my code modular and independent.
I am not using Rest Adapter for retrofit.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not using Rest Adapter for retrofit" ?

Comment: I am using Retrofit 2.0 and in Retrofit 2.0 RestAdapter has been replaced by Retrofit.

Comment: If the base urls are different, I think it would be easiest to have a different instance for each.  Though I believe it is possible to change the base url for each call.

Comment: Base url is same. Though it might be possible that different header fields are used for every web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using just one base URL, you should be fine with just one instance of Retrofit.  Your interface will have three methods in it, and they can have whatever query and/or header parameters are needed.  You can also use a request interceptor to add header values if that works better for you.

Comment: thanks. I am using Interceptor to add header in my code via OkHTTP.Builder class.
now I have a separate single method to get retrofit instance which sets its client like retrofit.setClient(myOkHttpClient).

Now correct me if i am wrong...with different interceptor header for different webservices do I have to create different OkHTTP Client with their respective interceptor and then set these http client to my single retrofit instance using switch case or any other filteration method.

Comment: Unless the interceptor can figure out what to do when it intercepts the request, yes I think that's what you would have to do.